# php record not inserting database when click on submit event

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble inserting a simple row into a `mysql` database.

My code is:

```
<?php   
    include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/riteshproject/config.php");    
    include('../config.php')
?>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Add'])) {          
        $query1="INSERT INTO flatmaster(flat) VALUES ('123')";
        mysql_query($query1);
    }?>

 <input type="Submit" name="Add" id="add" value="Add">
```

I want to insert the row into the flatmaster table when I click on submit.

my whole code is

```
<?php   
    include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/riteshproject/config.php");    
    include('../config.php')     ?>

<?php
         /*if(isset($_POST['Add']))          {
           $aria=$_POST['area'];
           $custname=$_POST['custname'];
           $mob1=$_POST['mob1'];
           $mob2=$_POST['mob2'];
           $flatbunglo=$_POST['flatbungalo'];
           $address=$_POST['address'];
           $bhk=$_POST['bhk'];
           $rent=$_POST['rent'];
           $diposit=$_POST['diposit'];
           $sqft=$_POST['sqft'];
           $floor=$_POST['floor'];
           $lift=$_POST['lift'];
                    echo   $addquery="insert into propertymaster (area,custname,mob1,mob2,proptype,address,bhk,rent,diposit,sqft,floor,lift)
                      values ('$aria','$custname','$mob1','$mob2','$flatbunglo','$address','$bhk','$rent','$diposit','$sqft','$floor','$lift')";
            mysql_query($addquery);
                 }*/
                 if(isset($_POST['Add']))   {           
             $query1="INSERT INTO flatmaster(flat) VALUES ('123')";             mysql_query($query1);
            }
          ?> <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>   <title>Shree Shree Property,kolhapur</title>   <meta charset="utf-8">   <meta
name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;}     .active { background-color: #00bfff; } 
    }

       </style> </head> <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="../home.php" class="active">Home</a></li>      <li class="current" id="dddd"><a href="../aboutus.php" >About
US</a></li>         <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Property</a></li>       <li><a href="#">Luxarious Property</a></li>         <li><a href="#">Property For
Sale</a></li>       <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
             </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">      <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-log-in"></span>Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>   </div> </nav>    <div class="container-fluid text-center">       <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">  <html> <body> <div id="wrap2">    <form>  <?php include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all
secure pages ?>     <h4>Welcome Mr.<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>!</h4>    </form>     <form>    <html>
       <body>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td width='100px' >
              </td>

              <td align="right">
                Area:
              </td>
              <td style="text-align:left" width="100px">

                                    <select name="area"  id="area" value="select">
                                    <option value="SELECT" style="display:none">SELECT</option>
                                        <?php 

                                            $query="select code,areaname from areamaster";
                                            $query_run=mysql_query($query);
                                            mysql_num_rows($query_run);

                                            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))

                                            {
                                            ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $row['code']?>"><?php echo $row['areaname']?></option>
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="space1">
              <td width='100px' >
              </td>

              <td align="right">
                Customer Name:
              </td>
              <td>
               <input type="text" id="custname" name="custname" size="40">
              </td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
              <td width='100px' >
              </td>

              <td align="right">
                Mobile No 1:
              </td>
              <td>
               <input type="text" id="mob1" name="mob1">
              </td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
              <td width='100px' >
              </td>

              <td align="right">
                Mobile No 2:
              </td>
              <td>
               <input type="text" id="mob2" name="mob2">
              </td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
           <td>
           </td>
             <td><b>FLAT DETAILS:</b>
             </td>

           </tr>
                     <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                Flat/Bungalo:
              </td>
           <td>
          <select name="flatbungalo"  id="flatbungalo" value="select">
                                    <option>Flat</option>
                                    <option>Bungalo</option>
                                    <option>House</option>

          </select>
          </td>          </tr> 

          <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                Property Address:
              </td>
           <td><input type="text" id ="address" name ="address" size="40">
           </td>         </tr> 

         <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                BHK:
              </td>
           <td>
          <select name="bhk"  id="bhk" value="select">
                                    <option>1 BHK</option>
                                    <option>2 BHK</option>
                                    <option>3 BHK</option>
                                    <option>4 BHK</option>

          </select>
          </td>          </tr> 
                 <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                RENT:
              </td>
           <td><input type="text" id ="rent" name ="rent" size="10">
           </td>         </tr>  

          <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                Diposit:
              </td>
           <td><input type="text" id ="diposit" name ="diposit" size="10">
           </td>         </tr> 
                 <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                SQ Ft:
              </td>
           <td><input type="text" id ="sqft" name ="sqft" size="10">
           </td>         </tr> 
                 <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                Floor:
              </td>
           <td><input type="text" id ="floor" name ="floor" size="10">
           </td>         </tr>

            <tr>
           <td width='100px' >
           </td>
           <td align="right">
                Lift:
              </td>
           <td>
          <select name="lift"  id="lift" value="select">
                                    <option>Yes</option>
                                    <option>No</option>


          </select>
          </td>          </tr>  

         <tr height="20">
         </tr>       
                 <tr>
           <td>
           </td>
           <td>
           </td>         <td align="left"><form method="POST"><input type="Submit" name="Add" id="add" value="Add"></form>
           </td>         </tr>
                </table>      </html>   </form> </div>    </body> </html>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>   </div> </div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">   <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: Where do you connect to the database?  Turn on error reporting, check error logs, check `mysql_error()` for errors.

Comment: form tags, method etc.???

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: i connected to databse through <?php  
 include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/riteshproject/config.php"); 
    include('../config.php') 
?>

Comment: i am trying to insert simple record into a table which having only one field

Comment: can i send whole php file?

Comment: one thing is that , i used drop down option in that i selected options from database so i thing i have connected to database well

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your submit button inside a `form` and use `POST` to send data:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Add'])) {         
$query1="INSERT INTO flatmaster(flat) VALUES ('123')";
mysql_query($query1);
}  
?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="Submit" name="Add" id="add" value="Add">
</form>
```

*Warning! Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks! [How do I prevent SQL Injection Attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*

Comment: yes my input type is in form tag

Comment: but still not working

Comment: @RiteshFondke When you say _"not working"_, could you explain further?

Comment: my input type is  <td align="left"><form method="POST"><input type="Submit" name="Add" id="add" value="Add"></form>
     </td>

Comment: but record not inserting to table

Comment: @RiteshFondke Place `echo mysql_error();` under `mysql_query` and let me know the error it displays when you click submit.

Comment: i am new with php mysql can you plz tell me how can i echo mysql_error();

Comment: @RiteshFondke Simply paste `echo mysql_error();` under `mysql_query`

Comment: i have paste echo mysql_error();  like      $query1="INSERT INTO flatmaster(flat) VALUES ('123')";
   echo mysql_error();
   mysql_query($query1); is it okk?

Comment: @RiteshFondke Put `echo mysql_error();` under `mysql_query($query1);` - you put it the other way around!

Comment: YES I HAVE PUT MYSQL_ERROR() BUT IT NOT SHOWING ANY ERROR AFTER CLICKING ON ADD BUTTON